# Neo4j- How can I match by using the internal ID

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neomodel

I need to retrieve a node in Neo4j and I only have the internal ID.

Is there a way to retrieve the node that has the ID in the given set in one cypher query ?

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.5

Thanks !

```
from neomodel import db
query="MATCH (n:Message) WHERE ID(n)="+id+" SET n.type='"+str(ans)+"', n.reprimands='"+str(ans2)+"'"
db.cypher_query(query)
```

I tried this but it didn't work out. I asigned the id in the python code, but it didn't seemed to have matched the ID I already had in my neo4j db. I used SET to change some attributes in the db but nothing changed at all.

I am using neomodel to access the DB via python.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work out" (did you get an error, the wrong result, no result, ...)? Also, the code shown ignores the query result, so how do you know you know it did not work out? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have `ID` capitalized.

Also, it looks like you're naming the python variable with `id`. That's already a [python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), so I'd recommend naming the variable something like `databaseId`. You code would become...

```py
from neomodel import db
query="MATCH (n:Message) WHERE id(n)="+databaseId+" SET n.type='"+str(ans)+"', n.reprimands='"+str(ans2)+"'"
db.cypher_query(query)
```

The cypher would look something like this:

```
MATCH (n:Message)
  WHERE id(n) = 123
SET n.type = "some type",
    n.reprimands = "some reprimands"
```

Comment: By the way, the `id()` function in Neo4j is deprecated in favor of `elementId()`. It's not something you want to implement now, since you're on such an old version of Neo4j, but keep it in mind for the future if you're building queries around the internal identifier values.

Comment: I cannot set the internal ID it is already given by the database itself, I have no influence in naming this attribute. But thank you for your time and help...

Comment: You do not need to rename the variable in python - that was just a suggestion if you had the capability. The code I wrote above should still work fine with `id` instead of `databaseId`. Again, I think the issue you were having is that you had capital `ID` in your cypher query.